# IOS - IB : using UITableView in UIViewcontroller, please help me

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

im newbie IOS and using IB, im working UITableView in UIViewController, i have implement "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource" in viewcontroller and setdelegate,datasource for uitableview but it dosen't work, i dont know,

please help me!

thank for your read this article.

code viewcontroller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource> @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

code viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];
    dispatch_async(htvque, ^{
               NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: listFilmByCate];
        NSError* error;
        jsonTable = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        listDataTable = [jsonTable objectForKey:@"List"];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [tableView reloadData];
        });
    });

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return listDataTable.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *dataTable = [listDataTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    NSData *receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[dataTable objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"]objectForKey:@"Url1"]]];    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:50 topCapHeight:80];

    static NSString *simple_cell = @"simpleCell";

    CustomizeCell_Home *customize_cell = (CustomizeCell_Home *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple_cell];
    if (simple_cell == nil) 
    {}

    customize_cell.imageView.image = image;
    customize_cell.lbldescription.text =[dataTable objectForKey:@"LongDescription"];
    customize_cell.lblTitle.text =  [dataTable objectForKey:@"VName"];
    customize_cell.lblTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    customize_cell.lbldescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    customize_cell.lbldescription.numberOfLines=4;
    customize_cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtblRight.png"]];
    return customize_cell;
}
```

Comment: hi CBredlow, I want to show uitableview inside uiviewcontroller? i setdelegate and datasource for it but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

in this line of code is your problem:

```
CustomizeCell_Home *customize_cell = (CustomizeCell_Home *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple_cell];
if (simple_cell == nil) 
{}
```

what would happens if `customize_cell` is `nil`?

you are not instanciating the `customize_cell` and because of that you cant call these methods:

```
customize_cell.imageView.image = image;
customize_cell.lbldescription.text =[dataTable objectForKey:@"LongDescription"];
customize_cell.lblTitle.text =  [dataTable objectForKey:@"VName"];
customize_cell.lblTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
customize_cell.lbldescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
customize_cell.lbldescription.numberOfLines=4;
customize_cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtblRight.png"]];
return customize_cell;
```

just add a simple inicialize cell inside the if, like this:

```
if (customize_cell == nil) 
{
  customize_cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"AnIdentifierString"] autorelease];
}
```

**EDIT**

change this:

```
CustomizeCell_Home *customize_cell = (CustomizeCell_Home *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple_cell];
if (simple_cell == nil) 
{}

customize_cell.lbldescription.text =[dataTable objectForKey:@"LongDescription"];
customize_cell.lblTitle.text =  [dataTable objectForKey:@"VName"];
customize_cell.lblTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
customize_cell.lbldescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
customize_cell.lbldescription.numberOfLines=4;
customize_cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtblRight.png"]];
return customize_cell;
```

to:

```
CustomizeCell_Home *customize_cell = (CustomizeCell_Home *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple_cell];
if (customize_cell == nil) 
{
  customize_cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"AnIdentifierString"] autorelease];
}

customize_cell.lbldescription.text =[dataTable objectForKey:@"LongDescription"];
customize_cell.lblTitle.text =  [dataTable objectForKey:@"VName"];
customize_cell.lblTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
customize_cell.lbldescription.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap | UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
customize_cell.lbldescription.numberOfLines=4;
customize_cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtblRight.png"]];
return customize_cell;
```

Comment: hi nicos karalis, i declare like you but uitableview still doesn't show data

Comment: put it on github and post the link here. its easier this way

Comment: just to be sure, are you 100% certain that your ``listDataTable`` is not empty? or the json that you load is really being loaded?

Comment: this link is my project http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?4ji84io6mex6nlp hope to receiving your help soon

Comment: i have looked your code and i couldnt find any problems. have you checked the json that is parsed? i cant check if your server is giving the right answare, but check if the NSData is not nil and put a NSLog right after this line ``listDataTable = [jsonTable objectForKey:@"List"];`` to see if this array is populated

Comment: u can see Json in http://mocku.ps/2mhyhg, yeah i could not found problems but i dont know why it doesn't work :-S

Answer (score 0):

Set,

tableView. dataSource = self;
tableView. delegate = self;

Implement **protocol** which are directed as **@required** means to say **mandatory**

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{
    // dint concentrate on this part, hope u are right
    NSDictionary *dataTable = [listDataTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    NSData *receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[dataTable objectForKey:@"Thumbnail"]objectForKey:@"Url1"]]];    
    UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:50 topCapHeight:80];

    static NSString *simple_cell = @"simpleCell";
    // works like double ended queue.... cells are re-used when available... so when cell is nil, u need to create
    CustomizeCell_Home *customize_cell = (CustomizeCell_Home *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple_cell];  
    if (simple_cell == nil) 
    {
         // CustomizeCell_Home is linked to CustomizeCell_Home_Reference using nib,
         [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"CustomizeCell_Home" owner: self options: nil];

         customize_cell = CustomizeCell_Home_Reference;
    }
    .....  
    .....  
    return customize_cell;
```

}

Comment: hi, Ashwin Kumar, i checked again code and i don't know why it doesn't work & doesn't show error :(

Comment: can u post the code... so that i get to no wats the problem.... And how did u create CustomizeCell_Home

Comment: this link my code  http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?im0064q9m6kjie4, JSon view in mocku.ps/2mhyhg , i setdelegate and datasource but it not work ...

Answer (score -1):

First thing, the cells are never allocated, instead of doing if(simple_cell==nil), you should do if(customize_cell==nil) and do the initialization code there.  Otherwise you're comparing a string that you just created and set a value to against nil.

Comment: hate to disapoint you, but ``simple_cell`` is a ``static NSString``

Comment: yep i edited so:customize_cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simple_cell];